# Is there a way to create a variable that matches T argument in a generic class?

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class, let's call it `Parser<T>`. In the main program, I would like to create an instance of `Parser` where `T` depends on the input parameters (because there would be a lot of options).
For instance, I have a variable `Class x = BigInteger.class`. So that means that I want `T` to be `BigInteger`.

Is there a possible way to use my variable instead of `T` to get `Parser<BigInteger>`? If not how would you recommend to do it?

P.S. I'm new to Java and also not a native English speaker, so I understand that the question may be very silly or has already been answered, if that's the case, I'm sorry.

Comment: Do you want to get `Class` of `T` in `Parser<T>`?

Comment: No, I want to use a variable to define the type of `T`, when creating an instance in the main program. I want something like `Parser p = new Parser<a>`, where `a` is variable that defines `BigInteger`, to be equivalent to `Parser p = new Parser<BigInteger>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good way to do that.  Explicit or inferred type parameters have to static (compile time) types.

By the sounds of it, you may be better off with a non-generic type that takes a `Class` as a parameter.

If you stick with generics you will probably end up with something ugly, like this:

```
 if (class.getName().equals("java.lang.BigInteger")) {
     BigInteger i = new Parser<BigInteger>().parse(someString);
     // do something with 'i'
 } else if (...) {
     // ad nauseum
 }
```

It is also possible that you would be better off with the type parameter on the `parse` method rather than the class; e.g.

```
 class Parser {
    <T> parse(Class<T> expected, String input) {
       // do parsing of input
       if (expected.isInstance(result)) {
           return expected.cast(result) {
       } else {
           // throw some exception
       }
 }
```

But even then, the caller needs a separate static call for each case if it is going to make use of the return type; e.g.

```
if (class.getName().equals("java.lang.BigInteger")) {
     BigInteger i = parser.parse(BigInteger.class, someString);
     // do something with 'i'
 } else if (...) {
     // ad nauseum
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your variable to the constructor.

```
public class Parser<T> {

    final Class<T> clazz;

    public Parser(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Parser<" + clazz.getSimpleName() + ">";
    }
}
```

and

```
Class a = BigInteger.class;
Parser parser1 = new Parser(a);
System.out.println(parser1);

Class b = String.class;
Parser parser2 = new Parser(b);
System.out.println(parser2);
```

->

```
Parser<BigInteger>
Parser<String>
```